# how i can modify style of html element generated dinamically?

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code:

```
function createfunc(i) {
    return function() {
        document.getElementById('id'+i).style.color='red';
        document.getElementById('id'+i).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
    } 
}
function onDeviceReady() {   
    var olnew = document.createElement("ul");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var newLi = document.createElement("li");
        var title = document.createElement('h2');
        title.id="id"+i;
        title.innerHTML = i;
        newLi.appendChild(title);
        newLi.onclick =createfunc(i);
        olnew.appendChild(newLi);
    }
}
```

But when i click on the li element it not change the color or the text

thanks very much

UPDATE

The original code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function createfunc(i) {
        return function() {
           document.getElementById('id'+i).style.color='red';
           document.getElementById('id'+i).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
                          } 
                               }
        function onDeviceReady() {   
           var olnew = document.getElementById('ordenes');
           for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               var newLi = document.createElement("li");
               var title = document.createElement('h2');
               title.id="id"+i;
               title.innerHTML = i;
               newLi.appendChild(title);
               newLi.onclick =createfunc(i);
               olnew.appendChild(newLi);
                                   }
                   }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onDeviceReady();">
        <div id="layout">
            <ul id="ordenes" ></ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click the li, no change, the li elements have the id, but not work

Comment: Working fine..Where have you appended `UL` element ?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i update the code, thanks

Comment: It does change it to `red` and text to `"Paragraph changed!"`

Comment: Yes, it work, my problem was a bracket... thanks very much, but... there are a better way for make this functionality? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining `ID` attributes, use `this` context in `handler-function` which represents `Element` on which event is invoked and use `querySelector` to select `child` of the Element.

```js
function createfunc() {
  this.querySelector('h2').style.color = 'red';
  this.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  var olnew = document.getElementById('ordenes');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    var title = document.createElement('h2');
    title.innerHTML = i;
    newLi.appendChild(title);
    newLi.onclick = createfunc;
    olnew.appendChild(newLi);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="onDeviceReady();">
  <div id="layout">
    <ul id="ordenes"></ul>
  </div>
</body>
```